# How does combineLatest RxJS operator works when multiple observables emit values at the same time?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, combinelatest

The [RxJS Documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest) states that

> *combineLatest* Combines multiple Observables to create an Observable whose values are calculated from the latest values of each of its input Observables.

I want to understand how *combineLatest* works when multiple observables emit values at the same time?

If we look at the following code

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { timer, take, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `Hello`,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor() {
    const a$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(take(5)); //Emit values after each second (total 5 values)

    const b$ = timer(0, 4000).pipe(take(5)); //Emit values after every 4 seconds (total 5 values)

    //Marble Diagram
    
    //0 1 2 3 4
    //0       1       2       3       4

    const result$ = combineLatest(a$, b$);

    result$.subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

The output is as follows
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrGUH.png)
In the output above, at the 4th second the *result$* observable outputs the values [4,0] and [4,1]
simultaneously.

My question is, Why it does not prints only [4,1] since the combineLatest brings the latest value and "4" is the latest value from observable *a$* and "1" is the latest value from observable *b$* at the 4th second.

[Link to Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vitju1?devToolsHeight=33&file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To expand upon BizzyBobs good answer: since JS is single-threaded by nature, two event's can't happen at exactly the same time. Secondly, when using timers you always have some tolerance. The interval between two emissions of `timer(0,. 1000)` is never _exactly_ 1000ms, but a_at least_ 1000ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After each source emits at least one value, [`combineLatest`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest) emits whenever any of its source observables emit.

Even if two observables emit "at the same time" (*I'm assuming you really mean in the same event loop*), `combineLatest` will emit twice.

If you want to prevent emissions that occur in the same event loop, you could use [`debounceTime(0)`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/debounceTime):

```
result$ = combineLatest(a$, b$).pipe(debounceTime(0));
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you for the to the point answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use it like this:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { timer, take, withLatestFrom } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `Hello`,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor() {
    const a$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(take(5)); //Emit values after each second (total 5 values)

    const b$ = timer(0, 4000).pipe(take(5)); //Emit values after every 4 seconds (total 5 values)

    const result$ = a$.pipe(withLatestFrom(b$, (a, b) => [a, b]));

    result$.subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsyobe?file=src/main.ts

Comment: This provides a different behavior than `combineLastest`.  `combineLastest` will emit when `a$` or `b$` emits.  This solution only emits when `a$` emits.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. OP asked why his code behaves as it does. Also, when posting code in an answer it's always helpful to *explain* the code, i.e. why it's better, how it solves a particular problem, etc.

Comment: I second BizzyBob and churill 's thoughts. Thanks anyway for trying!