# RxJS combineLatest emit only once per path

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs-marbles

Is there any way/pattern to use `combineLatest()` or some other operator so that if the combined observables depend on one another, they will only emit only once for each set of paths with the same origin in a DAG? I think it may be easier to explain with a diagram.

Diagram:

```
   A C
  /| |
 B | |
  \|/
   D
```

Here B is subscribed to A, and D is subscribed to A, B, and C. The default behavior is that **if A emits, D emits twice**: once when A emits, and once more when B emits (as a result of A emitting). I would like it to emit **only once**, after both have emitted. However, if C emits, then D should emit immediately as well.

Here's the code:

```
const A = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(1);
const B = A.pipe(Rx.map((x) => x + 1));
const C = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(3);

const D = Rx.combineLatest({ A, B, C });

D.subscribe(console.log); // {A: 1, B: 2, C: 3}
A.next(2); // Two emissions: {A: 2, B: 2, C: 3}, {A: 2, B: 3, C: 3} 
// Would like the second one ONLY, i.e. {A: 2, B: 3, C: 3}
C.next(4); // Correctly emits: {A: 2, B: 3, C: 4}
```

One solution I've tried is to linearize it and make the entire collection of A, B, and C an observable:

```
 {A, C}
    |
{A, C, B}
    |
   {D}
```

This works but I wonder if there's perhaps a better way.

Comment: If the observable streams aren’t performing any expensive side effects, using [`debounceTime(0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75074303/how-does-combinelatest-rxjs-operator-works-when-multiple-observables-emit-values/75075776#75075776) can work well as a simple solution.

Comment: Not knowing whether B is a result of a pipe from A is the real problem here. If you have control over the creation of B, you could use `combineLatestWith` as the last stage of the pipe along with A for example. If you have no control over the creation of B, I don't think what you're looking for is possible without design changes, since I'm not familiar with a way to get the "origin" Observable from another Observable, since essentially, a pipe operator is simply a function. In cases such as these, it's usually better to redesign since it's usually a good indication of a design flaw.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right the question, you want that the final Observable `D` emits any time either `A` (the upstream of `B`) or `C` emit but, if `A` emits, you want also the value emitted by `B`.

If this is the case, I would make sure that any time `B` emits, it emits not only the value of `B` but also the value notified by its upstream `A`, and then I would pass to `combineLatest` only `B` and `C`, like this

```
const A = new BehaviorSubject(1);
const B = A.pipe(map((x) => [x, x + 1]));
const C = new BehaviorSubject(3);

const D = combineLatest({ B, C }).pipe(
  map((val) => ({ A: val.B[0], B: val.B[1], C: val.C }))
);
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah that works. However, for it to work, I do need to know that A is the parent of B beforehand. I'm trying to implement this in a situation where observables are added dynamically & I may not know whether an observable is a parent or a child of another one. Any idea what to do in that situation?

Comment: Downstream, i.e. in the final subscription, you want one notification whenever A emits, no matter how many "derived" Observables/streams you have. If this is the case, rather than creating Observable `B`, you should have a `map` operator attached to Observable `A` that transforms any value notified by Observable `A` into the tuple you are interested in. Which means to create a chain of transformations which starts from a value emitted by A and then is composed down the way. I think a general implementation of this chain could be very complex. Maybe is feasible in more constrained situations.

Answer (score -1):

you can `zip` A,B, together so for every pair of emissions you get only one in D. Combine that with C which is just one:

```
const A = new BehaviorSubject(1);
const B = A.pipe(map((x) => [x, x + 1]));
const C = new BehaviorSubject(3);


const D = combineLatest({ zip(A,B), C })
```

This requires both A & B to emit a value but because those depend on eachother that is not an issue in your example.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip